# Issues creating packing slip with page breaks

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Ok, I'm going nuts here.  I'm trying to create an order packing slip but having trouble grouping it all properly.  A few details:

- There can be multiple items on each packing slip(InventoryDescription & InventoryItemCount in my query below)
- Packing slip needs to page break on each order id.
- I need to also include in the footer, a message saying to contact customer service (see 2nd image below).  This needs to be on the footer of each invoice.

Here's a sample of my data.  The first 2 rows (John Smith.  OrderID 40184) are multiple items within the same orderID, so they should be on the same packing slip.  The other 2 rows (Amy Andrews & Paul Johnson) should each be on their own separate packing slip.
[image]

Here's an image of my work so far.  I inserted a tablix, tried inserting everything into the data rows, then grouping on OrderID & ShipTo.  The orderId group has a page break "Between each instance of a group" checked.

[image]

I've also provided a link to my current (mess of a) report, if you'd like to review.
[PackingSlip.zip](http://www.netmarketingllc.com/client/MyFiles/PackingSlip.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a List. Insert a list, and group it on orderId. Set the Group to page break between each instance of the group as you had done. What you will find is that the contents of the  List (which is actually just a rectangle) will be repeated for each Order Id the report encounters. You can pretty much just put everything on your current report within that List and it should work fine, including the table to group your InventoryDescription, InventoryItemCount etc. Only the ones that are against the OrderId in question will be shown on each slip